# Visual Studio multiline reg-exp to remove duplicate using statements

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008, duplicates

I need regular expression to remove duplicate using statements.

```
using NS.SN.Services.Common;
using NS.SN.Data.BaseRegistry;
using NS.SN.Data.DataContracts.Registry;
using NS.SN.Services.Common; <-- this one must go
using NS.SN.Services.DataContracts;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Transactions;
using CodeEnums = NS.SN.Data.DataContracts.Enums.CodeEnums;
using System.Linq;
```

Problem is that this reg-exp does not work because ([.:b]*\n)* matches only first new-line char. Can I fix this reg-exp?

> {:b*using:bNS.SN.Services.Common;([.:b]*\n)*}using:bNS.SN.\Services.\Common;:b*\n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this as "Find what":

```
{:b*using:bNS\.SN\.Services\.Common;(.*\n)*}using:bNS\.SN\.Services\.Common;:b*\n
```

and this as "Replace with":

```
\1
```

**UPDATE:**
I completely missed the dot inside the character group:
`[.:b]*` will match the dot or the colon or the letter b, because it is inside a character class! What you meant is `(.|:b)*`, where the `:b` is redundant, because it is contained inside "any character" (`.`), so it simply should be `.*`. See the updated regex above.

Comment: What is difference bettwen [:b.\n]* and [^\n\n]*? BTW - it is very very slow!

Comment: `:b` only matches a space or tab. `[^\n]` matches anything that is not a newline. Your main problem was, that you didn't match all those usings in between.

Comment: why? I tell - match char, space OR newline multiple times [.:b\n]*. Or is this not how REGEXP works?

Comment: Ah, you are right, I completely missed that. I updated my answer, please have a look.

Comment: Allright! This works! (only it is incredibly SLOOOOOW! :( ) ... wait - i can improve speed by replacing (.*\n)* with (:b*using.*\n)*!